# How to get rid of the error message in Powershell when listing more than 5000 blobs with Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, powershell, command-line-interface, azure-blob-storage

For a cleanup script on some (+10k) blobs in a container in an Azure Storage account, we first select all blobs and count them using the following command:

```
 (az storage blob list --num-results * --account-name "ourstorageaccount" --container-name "ourcontainer" --query "[*].name").Length
```

We especially added the --num-results to make sure more than 5000 blobs are returned, but still we see the following error in powershell:

```
az : WARNING: Next Marker:
At line:1 char:2
+ (az storage blob list --num-results * --account-name "ourstorageaccount" - ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (WARNING: Next Marker::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

WARNING: 2!152!MDAwMDY5IUZQLVBTUUwtMjAxNi0wMSRQUk9EX0lkZW50aXR5U2VydmVyNFBlcnNpc3RlZF9MT0dfMjAxOTA0MDhybiEwMDAwMjghOTk5OS0xMi0zMVQyMzo1OTo1OS45OTk5OTk5WiE-
```

The result of the command is correct, but the error makes it look like something went wrong.
We would like to suppress the message, or adapt the command in a way thay the error does not show.

Azure CLI version:

```
azure-cli                         2.0.62

acr                                2.2.4
acs                               2.3.21
advisor                            2.0.0
ams                                0.4.4
appservice                        0.2.17
backup                             1.2.3
batch                              4.0.0
batchai                            0.4.8
billing                            0.2.1
botservice                        0.1.10
cdn                                0.2.2
cloud                              2.1.1
cognitiveservices                  0.2.5
command-modules-nspkg               2.0.2
configure                         2.0.21
consumption                        0.4.2
container                         0.3.16
core                              2.0.62
cosmosdb                           0.2.9
dla                                0.2.5
dls                                0.1.8
dms                                0.1.3
eventgrid                          0.2.2
eventhubs                          0.3.4
extension                          0.2.5
feedback                           2.2.0
find                               0.3.2
hdinsight                          0.3.3
interactive                        0.4.3
iot                                0.3.7
iotcentral                         0.1.6
keyvault                          2.2.14
kusto                              0.2.2
lab                                0.1.6
maps                               0.3.4
monitor                           0.2.12
network                            2.3.6
nspkg                              3.0.3
policyinsights                     0.1.2
privatedns                         1.0.0
profile                            2.1.5
rdbms                              0.3.9
redis                              0.4.2
relay                              0.1.4
reservations                       0.4.2
resource                          2.1.13
role                               2.5.0
search                             0.1.1
security                           0.1.1
servicebus                         0.3.4
servicefabric                     0.1.16
signalr                            1.0.0
sql                                2.2.1
sqlvm                              0.1.1
storage                            2.4.0
telemetry                          1.0.2
vm                                2.2.18
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` flag, which ignores the errors that are displayed as a result of the command. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Would not the earlier solution be for PowerShell? The question is about AzureCLI, so to suppress the error message, the only way I know of is to route the stderr to /dev/null by adding 2>/dev/null to the end of the command.